# Unable to pass filename with space through variable to SCP command

Tags: linux, shell, sh, scp

I am trying to set the variable `$file` as "Unavailable Voucher's Report_Apr-2017.txt". It is getting set to the variable successfully. But I am getting an error when I use this variable in a SCP command inside my script. I have tried to replace the ' '(space) with '\ '(escaping space), still no use.

```
[***]# scp $file user@remoteserver:/path
```

Error be like:

```
Unavailable\\: No such file or directory
Voucher's\\: No such file or directory
Report_Apr-2017.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Putting `\ ` inside your variable actually makes the problem *worse*, not better. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for an explanation of why that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to double quote the var:

```
file="Unavailable Voucher's Report_Apr-2017.txt"
scp "$file" user@remoteserver:/path
```

Comment: how to escape both ' '(space) and '(single quote) in a single command. i have tried Rfile=$(sed -e 's/ /\ /g';'s/\'/\\'/g' <<<"$file") but not working

Comment: "Bracing" is not necessary.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio can you help me to copy files into remote server. the filename must have spaces. i want to pass the filename using a variable.

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan, using `sed` changes your data itself -- it creates **literal** quotes. The only quotes that matter to the shell are **syntactic** quotes. Syntactic quotes aren't part of the data; instead, they're instructions to the shell. So using `sed` or anything like it to modify quotes or backticks is counterproductive.

Comment: i tried replacing the space and quote thats why i gone for sed. anyways thats not working. Now help me just to copy the filename with space into remote server by assigning filename to a variable .

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan Try the lines in my answer and if it is not working copy the output into your question.